# Google maps will not render until page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

```
<a href="<?php echo 'https://maps.google.com/?q='.$listing->get_address1().$listing->get_city().$listing->get_state()?>" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" style="width:125px;height:125px;padding-top:8px">

  <div id ="map-canvas" style="width:125px;height:125px;"></div>

  <div id ="full_map" style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC;padding-top:2px;font-size:12px;text-align:center;position:relative;top:-24px;left:7px;width:110px;height:16px;background-color:#FFFFFF">View Full Map</div>

    </a>
```

```
 var map;

 function codeaddress() {
     var address = "<?php echo $listing->get_address1()." ".$listing->get_city()." ".$listing->get_state(); ?>";
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     console.log(address);
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
     //alert('geocoding');
     if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        var mapOptions = {
                 center: results[0].geometry.location,
                 zoom: 10,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:results[0].geometry.location,
              icon:'icons/orange_marker.png'
     });
     marker.setMap(map);
     console.log(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
     //alert('marker done');
     console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
     }
     else{
          alert('Could not find address as ' + status);
     }
      });
      /google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeaddress());//google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'));
                    }
     $(document).ready(function(){
          codeaddress();
          //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          //alert('I am done here');
     });
```

The map-canvas gets populated every time the page is refreshed. I need to know how the map-canvas can be populated without refreshing the page. The address and geo codes are calculated in the function, but the map will not populate.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue, I solved it by triggering the Google maps **`resize`** event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: I did try that, do I need to place the call in a different location?

Comment: So, if i take the map's div outside the a tag, it works fine till the link is used. The link opens up google maps on the mobile device's browser. After clicking the back button on the browser, the map works fine, but if I move back to a previous page in the web app and try another listing, it will not render the map.